# Amazon Athena: Convert bigint timestamp to readable timestamp

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I am using Athena to query the date stored in a bigInt format. I want to convert it to a friendly timestamp.

I have tried:

```
from_unixtime(timestamp DIV 1000) AS readableDate
```

And

```
to_timestamp((timestamp::bigInt)/1000, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') at time zone 'UTC' as readableDate
```

I am getting errors for both. I am new to AWS. Please help!

Comment: Did you try `from_unixtime(timestamp / 1000)`?

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen you should add this as a proper answer! It just saved me!

Comment: @TomDalton at your service!

Answer (score 31):

Assuming you have `t` value representing "Java timestamp" (milliseconds since epoch), you can use [`from_unixtime`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#from_unixtime):

```
from_unixtime(timestamp / 1000e0)
```

If you want to discard the millisecond component of your timestamp value, this will do this:

```
from_unixtime(timestamp / 1000)
```

Comment: `from_unixtime(timestamp / 1000)` worked for me when looking at WAF logs.